# How to both execute Command and Button click in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have:

```
<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
  <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type locals:OneViewModel}}, 
Path=OneTappedView}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
</Grid.GestureRecognizers>

<Button x:Name="bt_one" Clicked="bt_one_Clicked"/>
```

When I do Grid Tap, Command and bt_one_Clicked execute concurrently? Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that via manipulating UI, but try to merge the logic behind?

Comment: Thank you, I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I do Grid Tap, Command and bt_one_Clicked execute concurrently?

Yes, you can add the button's clicked code in your grid tap event when tapping your grid.

You can  refer to the following code:

OnePage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:formapp1="clr-namespace:FormApp1"
             x:Class="FormApp1.OnePage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <formapp1:OneViewModel></formapp1:OneViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="600" BackgroundColor="Yellow">

                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"  Command="{Binding OneTappedViewCommand}"  />
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            </Grid>

            <Button x:Name="bt_one" Text="one button" Command="{Binding BtnOneClickedCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

OneViewModel.cs

```
 public class OneViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand OneTappedViewCommand { private set; get; }

    public ICommand BtnOneClickedCommand { private set; get; }

    public OneViewModel() {

        OneTappedViewCommand = new Command(GridTapped);
        BtnOneClickedCommand= new Command(btnOneClickedMthod);
    }

    private void GridTapped()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----111------> GridTapped is triggered......");


        //add one clicked method here 
        btnOneClickedMthod();
    }

    private void btnOneClickedMthod()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----222------> GridTapped is triggered......");
    }


    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Note:

In model `OneViewModel`, you can add `bt_one` event(`btnOneClickedMthod`) in grid tap function `GridTapped`.